# Padding is incorrect. AES encryption

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, padding

```
encrypted=b'$\x940\xc6\xef3s\x01|e\xe8\xdf\xaa00\xcc\x8c\x98i\x84\xcc[e\xd2\xa4]\xb37\xab\xbc@} \xaeC\xdd\xd7\x89\xdd[\xab)\xf0t\xa8\x95\xfe\xf9>\x15\x02:\x85-s*\x0cf\xe1\xa5\xc3\xa8]\x1d\x8f\xe2f\x1aje\x9f\xc3^\xe0\xc6i\xd6\x02$I\xce0_\x97\x8c\x06Rj\x1e\xe0F\x1fE\xfb\xf4\x0be:\x01\xd1m\xe4\xfaVv\xa0\xdf\xa8\x1e\xec\x03\xc1\x9a\x89\x9a\xa1m\xb4uL\x97\x81\xdc\xaaG5\xf7Q\xba\xc6\xf33\x05\x94l#pL!\x886\x9a5\xa3\xa2Z)\xd3\x80&p\xa4)\x1e\x9ei\xcc\xa9\xcc\xe9j\xe9\xb4\x14\xe1<\x8c\xa50\xd4\xf9\xb5\xb2\xd4#3\nwW#m\x14\xb67\xf3!a\x19:\x8af\x1c\xf1\x13\xbfM\x1a\xfe\xaf\xb0\x95Y~\xe2}\x06\xf0\xc1\xff\xde\x04\x06\xc9\xb4\xfe\xc8\xbb\x8eS\xff\xe29Q\xa0\xf6\xd2\xc78\xf5\x97\x07OW\xbb\xfd\x08q\x8f4C\xbb\x00\xa0\xa1_g\x0e3&x\\\x1a\xa4/a\xa2\x1bp|\x84\xdfr[.\xe5\xbd\xb1\xfc\xc3\t_0l\xddU\xc8HL@&LD\x17g=\xb5\xb0\xcf'

mk123=b'$\x940\xc6\xef3s\x01|e\xe8\xdf\xaa00\xcc\x8c\x98i\x84\xcc[e\xd2\xa4]\xb37\xab\xbc@} \xaeC\xdd\xd7\x89\xdd[\xab)\xf0t\xa8\x95\xfe\xf9>\x15\x02:\x85-s*\x0cf\xe1\xa5\xc3\xa8]\x1d\x8f\xe2f\x1aje\x9f\xc3^\xe0\xc6i\xd6\x02$I\xce0_\x97\x8c\x06Rj\x1e\xe0F\x1fE\xfb\xf4\x0be:\x01\xd1m\xe4\xfaVv\xa0\xdf\xa8\x1e\xec\x03\xc1\x9a\x89\x9a\xa1m\xb4uL\x97\x81\xdc\xaaG5\xf7Q\xba\xc6\xf33\x05\x94l#pL!\x886\x9a5\xa3\xa2Z)\xd3\x80&p\xa4)\x1e\x9ek\xcc\xa9\xcc\xe9j\xe9\xb4\x14\xe1<\x8c\xa50\xd4\xf9\xb5\xb2\xd4#3\nwW#m\x14\xb67\xf3!a\x19:\x8af\x1cq\x13\xbfM\x1a\xfe\x8f\xb0\x95Y~\xe2}\x06\xf0\xc1\xff\xde\x14\x06\xc9\xb4\xfe\xc8\xb3\x8eS\xff\xe29Q\xa0\xf6\xd2\xc78\xf5\x97\x07OW\xbb\xfd\x08q\x8f4C\xbb\x00\xa0\xa1_g\x0es&x\\\x1a\xa4/a\xa2\x1bp|\x84\xdbr[.\xe5\xbd\xb1\xbc\xe3\t_0L\xd9U\xc8HL@&LD\x17g=\xb5\xb0\xcf'
```

### note:ive done some process in between so the bytestrings mk123 and encrypted are not the same

the first byte string is the one ive got after encryption,but when i try to decode its throwing the error"padding is incoreect"
this is the code ive used

```
from hashlib import md5
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad

class AESCipher:
    def __init__(self, key):
        password = key.encode('utf-8')
        self.key = md5(password).digest()

    def encrypt(self, data):
        vector = get_random_bytes(AES.block_size)
        encryption_cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, vector)
        return vector + encryption_cipher.encrypt(pad(data,  AES.block_size))

    def decrypt(self, data):
        file_vector = data[:AES.block_size]
        decryption_cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, file_vector)
        return unpad(decryption_cipher.decrypt(data[AES.block_size:]), AES.block_size)
```

the driver code is

```
message='0000000000000000011111111111111001000010001011100101101011101110010000100010111001011010111011100101101000100010011111111111111001111111111111100101111011100010010111101110101001011110111010100101111011101010010001100010001001111111111111100000000000000000'
msg = message.encode('utf-8')
pwd = "password"
encrypted = AESCipher(pwd).encrypt(msg)
print('Ciphertext:', encrypted)
decrypted = AESCipher(pwd).decrypt(mk123).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: The original ciphertext can be decrypted, the modified (= corrupted) one cannot. What exactly is the question?

Comment: @Topaco i want to decrypt the modified ciphertext

Comment: Your changes to the ciphertext corrupt the data, especially the padding, hence the exception. Also, you get non-UTF8 compliant byte sequences throwing more exceptions during UTF-8 decoding. Omit unpadding and UTF-8 decoding, then you can decrypt the ciphertext. Of course, the original plaintext does not result. Honestly, I don't understand the purpose of what you're doing, nor what you're expecting.

Comment: @Topaco actually ive hid the ciphertext in an image(converted it into bytes->int->binary) then after retrieving again converted (binary->int->bytes) during this process some bits in the binary are changed so it resulted in change in ciphertext

Comment: Actually, a ciphertext (unlike plaintext) is not secret, so it does not need to be hidden. But if you do it anyway, your processing must be such that you can reproduce the *unaltered* ciphertext. Otherwise, the *original* plaintext can generally not be recovered.

Comment: @Topaco do you think there is any other alternative for this problrm like changing the mode or changing the encryption algorithm to?

Comment: No, you have to modify your process so that the unchanged ciphertext can be reconstructed.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the last block or the previous to last block of ciphertext then unpadding *may* indeed fail for CBC mode. This is because both of these blocks change the resulting plaintext. Generally, for CBC mode, you'll change the bits of one block with a chance of 0.5 for the block that you changed, and the same bits of the plaintext at the next block are flipped. How changes affect the decryption routine is called "error propagation".

You can figure most of this out yourself by looking at the decryption diagram from Wikipedia (by WhiteTimberwolf):

[image]

Knowing that, if you want to investigate the original plaintext you simply need to skip unpadding. Then you get the above changes made to the plaintext (including padding). You can then try to fix or guess the plaintext and/or correct the padding. If you cannot correct the padding then the size of the plaintext can differ by one block - as far as the cipher is concerned anyway.

Comment: finally does that mean if i remove the padding part ,i can decrypt a ciphertext (which is not the same as the original generated ciphertext)?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that the decrypt function doesn't fail, and that you will get a different plaintext of course. The idea is that a block cipher (AES in this case) always decrypts by itself. I'll add the diagram for CBC mode from Wikipedia to the answer.